# How to solve 'ImportError: No module named door_msgs.msg'?

Tags: python

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed [PR2 Opens a Door tutorial](http://ros.org/wiki/pr2_simulator/Tutorials/PR2OpenDoor/cturtle).

when I run

```
  hg clone https://kforge.ros.org/doors/hg
  svn co https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/stacks/motion_planning_common/trunk/mapping_msgs
  svn co https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/stacks/motion_planning_common/trunk/geometric_shapes_msgs
  
  export ROBOT=sim
  roslaunch pr2_doors_gazebo_demo pr2_doors_demo.launch
  rosrun pr2_doors_executive trigger_opendoor.py
```

It says:

```
  ira@ira-K42JP:~/code/ros/test$ rosrun pr2_doors_executive trigger_opendoor.py
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/ira/code/ros/sam_gazebo/hg/pr2_doors_executive/scripts/trigger_opendoor.py", line 33, in <module>
      import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('pr2_doors_executive')
    File "/opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src/roslib/launcher.py", line 75, in load_manifest
      sys.path = prefix + _generate_python_path(package_name, [], os.environ) + sys.path
    File "/opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src/roslib/launcher.py", line 131, in _generate_python_path
      raise roslib.packages.InvalidROSPkgException("While loading package '%s': %s"%(d.package, str(e)))
  roslib.packages.InvalidROSPkgException: While loading package 'pr2_doors_actions': While loading package 'door_handle_detector': While loading package 'mapping_msgs': While loading package 'geometric_shapes_msgs': Cannot locate installation of package geometric_shapes_msgs: [rospack] couldn't find package [geometric_shapes_msgs]. ROS_ROOT[/opt/ros/electric/ros] ROS_PACKAGE_PATH[/home/ira/code/ros:/opt/ros/electric/stacks]
  ira@ira-K42JP:~/code/ros/test$ rosrun pr2_doors_executive trigger_opendoor.py
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/ira/code/ros/sam_gazebo/hg/pr2_doors_executive/scripts/trigger_opendoor.py", line 37, in <module>
      from door_msgs.msg import DoorAction, DoorGoal, Door
  ImportError: No module named door_msgs.msg
  ira@ira-K42JP:~/code/ros/test$
```

How to solve it?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40620/how-to-solve-%27importerror:-no-module-named-door_msgs.msg%27-?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-08-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you execute

```
rosmake pr2_doors_executive
```

When you are installing packages from source, you need to rosmake them.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-08-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-08-06**:
I can run it. And it shows:Waiting for open door action server
Sending goal to open door action server.
But why pr2 doesn't move? I can't see PR2 do anything.

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-08-06**:
As @dornhege pointed out already, the code is written for cturtle and is probably unmaintained. I wouldn't expect it to work in electric.

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-08-06**:
Sure,you're right. But I think if I know how tofix it maybe I can learn more ROS. Or should I post on another question?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-08-06**:
If you do this to learn more, you'll need to debug what is going on, i.e. understand how it's supposed to work and then see where it hangs. But for learning how things in ROS work, I'd suggest taking something more recent as things might have changed drastically.

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-08-06**:
Where to start to figure out? And how to make sure what I need? Thank you~

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-08-06**:
Reading source code is always a good starting point. Use rxgraph, rostopic info, rostopic list, rosnode info and rosnode list to find out which nodes are connected/unconnected. Find out why the unconnected nodes are not connected and fix that by starting the missing nodes. And read source code :)